# Bluetooth completely disappeared from laptop?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, bluetooth, device-manager

I was trying to resolve a Bluetooth earphone stuttering issue on my laptop and [one of the articles I read](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-10-bluetooth-audio-stutter-fix/) suggested to pick the other bluetooth option for my earphones (picture from the article below).

[image]

I picked Headset while the selection was currently Headphones. Then I heard some static noise and my audio died. I thought a quick reboot would fix it but after rebooting my laptop, Windows is acting like it doesn't have any bluetooth at all whatsoever, so I checked Device Manager, and the Bluetooth entry is no longer there and now I have a new entry pictured below.

[image]

I tried uninstalling this device and then rebooting, it was still there, I then went to my laptop's manufacturer website and downloaded the Bluetooth driver, installed that and reboot, still nothing.

I don't know what else I should do. My laptop's speaker is still working but my Bluetooth is completely gone. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Bluetooth may be a separate daughter card on the wireless card and has died.

Comment: Does switching audio output while music is playing grounds for bluetooth hardware to die like that?

Comment: Also what do you mean by separate daughter carrd? I'm looking at replacements and most of them have Wifi and Bluetooth in the same card.

Comment: If Bluetooth is integrated onto the wireless card then you may need to replace the card

Comment: @John: This is a USB device.

Comment: @harrymc Don't some laptops use USB for internal devices such as the keyboard and trackpad? (I haven't got one to hand to check right now.)

Comment: @user9564371: Sometimes, deleting the USB host controller and letting everything get re-detected fixes unknown device issues. Details in the first part of my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1564980/881098).

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Yes, it's starting to look this way. I didn't know that this existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
So I've tried a bunch of different things to try and fix this, I uninstalled the original driver, restarted a bunch of times, uninstalled the paired Bluetooth devices from Device Manager (they were hidden along with the Bluetooth section)

But one thing I have never done through all this was visit the UEFI/BIOS. I did it once by going to Settings > Update & Security > Recovery > Advanced Startup. I didn't even change anything I exited Discarding changes and lo and behold, my Bluetooth is back, even the paired devices I uninstalled prior were back.

I have absolutely no idea what happened or why visiting the UEFI settings fixed it.

I was debating if I should post this as an answer since it technically solved my issue but it was by accident and I don't even know what I did.

Comment: Sometimes a bad connection is improved just by handling/moving the device. I hope that the problem doesn't come back.

Answer (score 1):

The error "Device Descriptor Request Failed" arrives when Device Manager
stops a hardware device because it informed Windows that it is having
some type of an unspecified problem. As the message says, the device
couldn't answer the request to describe itself.

You could try the device on another USB port, or in another computer.
If both will fail, then this device is broken.

If the device works elsewhere, then check if other USB device(s) work
on your computer. If this fails, then your USB ports have a problem.
If it succeeds, then something has changed that made the device
incompatible with your computer (weird and very rare, but sometimes it happens).

Comment: How do I move the laptop's internal bluetooth thing to someplace else?

Comment: If the device is an internal USB, then either the internal arrangement uses USB inside the box (weird) or the device is very badly reporting itself. If you don't want to get the computer repaired, the simplest solution would be to get a real external USB wireless/bluetooth adapter and forget about the broken internal one.

Comment: Well I somehow fixed the problem by visiting the UEFI settings